# IOS push notification banner

Tags: php, ios, laravel, apple-push-notifications

I am working in PHP. Now I want to send a notification that banner must not show on ios device but payload received by IOS device. This push notification will be sent from PHP.

Now I simply send the push notification in such a way that IOS device receive paylod only but must not show the banner and also not produce sound

```
{"aps":{"alert":"","badge":69,"sound":"","content-available":1,"mutable-content":1},"data":{"id":xxxxx,"badge":69,"type":"chat_message","message":"post.lambda sent you a message","content":"dmdnZ2c=","status":"S","sent_at":"2020-01-29T12:25:22Z","is_mute":true,"post":null}}
```

Above code that I write when I send this payload to IOS device then IOS device receive badge but not perform any other operation after receiving the notification
I did not found any solution that work perfectly in my case.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Have you done any research? Did you try anything? Didn't it work as expected? What did you expect and what happened?

Comment: Look into sending silent push notifications. Process is similar to normal push; just a different payload. Silent push can be somewhat flaky though because iOS can throttle or discard notifications but I think it might be your best shot in this case. I wrote a bit about it here: https://www.donnywals.com/updating-your-apps-with-silent-push-notifications/

Comment: @jrswgtr If send silent push notification then IOS received and show banner but sound is muted. But now I want to send push notification that IOS must receive the payload but not show the banner and must not sounded.

Comment: @RizwanSaleem No. Silent notifications are invisible to the user. They are designed to let your server inform your app that new content is available.

Comment: @CZ54 you I need to send silent push notification in this case device will received payload but not show the banner?